# How do I set the User-Agent header when making a request with Hyper?

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm trying to do a GET request to Github's API in Rust with the Hyper library, and with a user-agent string in the header. I haven't had luck compiling with `.header(UserAgent("string"))`. Would anyone be willing to propose an idiomatic way to accomplish what I want?

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::io::Read;

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::header::{Connection, Headers};

struct Subtasks {
    github: &'static str,
}

struct Tasks {
    rust: Subtasks,
    go:   Subtasks,
}

fn main() {
    // initialize struct and populate
    let tasks = Tasks {
        rust: Subtasks {
            github: "https://api.github.com/rust-lang/rust",
        },
        go: Subtasks {
            github: "https://api.github.com/golang/go",
        },
    };

    let client = Client::new();
    let mut result = client.get(tasks.rust.github)
        .header(Connection::close())
        .send()
        .unwrap();

    let mut body = String::new();
    result.read_to_string(&mut body).unwrap();

    println!("Response: {}", body);
}
```

Comment: Please *include the error* you get when requesting help in solving the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you were getting this sort of error?

```
src/main.rs:31:20: 31:28 error: mismatched types:
 expected `collections::string::String`,
    found `&'static str`
(expected struct `collections::string::String`,
    found &-ptr) [E0308]
src/main.rs:31  .header(UserAgent("string"))
```

If so, you can get it to work by using

```
.header(UserAgent("string".to_string()))
```

and bringing `UserAgent` into scope

```
use hyper::header::{Connection, Headers, UserAgent};
```

The problem would have been in the use of a string literal instead of a `String` when constructing the header, which is solved by calling the `to_string()` method on the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

With the more recent hyper 0.11, you can set the user agent like this:

```
let mut req = hyper::Request::new(hyper::Method::Get, url);
req.headers_mut().set(UserAgent::new("my agent"));
```

Converted to the following dependencies:

```
hyper = "0.11"
hyper-tls = "0.1"
tokio-core = "0.1"
futures = "0.1"
```

The whole example would thus be:

```
extern crate hyper;
extern crate hyper_tls;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate futures;

use std::io::{self, Write};

use futures::Future;
use futures::stream::Stream;

use hyper::Client;
use hyper::header::UserAgent;

struct Subtasks {
    github: &'static str,
}

struct Tasks {
    rust: Subtasks,
    go:   Subtasks,
}

fn main() {
    // initialize struct and populate
    let tasks = Tasks {
        rust: Subtasks {
            github: "https://api.github.com/rust-lang/rust",
        },
        go: Subtasks {
            github: "https://api.github.com/golang/go",
        },
    };

    let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();
    let client = Client::configure()
        .connector(hyper_tls::HttpsConnector::new(4, &handle).unwrap())
        .build(&handle);

    let url = tasks.rust.github.parse::<hyper::Uri>().unwrap();
    let mut req = hyper::Request::new(hyper::Method::Get, url);
    req.headers_mut().set(UserAgent::new("my agent"));

    let work = client.request(req).and_then(|res| {
        print!("Response: ");
        res.body().for_each(|chunk| {
            io::stdout().write_all(&chunk).map_err(From::from)
        })
    });

    core.run(work).unwrap();
}
```